# Django Rest Framework: Serialize User ManyToMany field by username

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have a field:

```
invited_guests = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

A requirement is IDs are not allowed to be exposed, instead username should be used.

How can I serialize this field based on username instead of id for create and update view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would be using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` but since you dont want id exposed `SlugRelatedField` is what you want. This should work:

```
invited_guests = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), many=True, slug_field="username")
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!